# List.map not executing despite List having elements inside(flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I retrieve a `querysnapshot` from Firestore, which returns a list of querydocumentsnapshot with snapshot.docs, but when I try to map it nothing happens. If I use a `for...in` loop it works perfectly.

```dart
     QuerySnapshot snap =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).collection('ItemDetails').get();
    print(snap.docs);//returns [Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot']

    for (var item in snap.docs.toList()) {//this executes perfectly
      print(item.data());
    }
    snap.docs.toList().map((e) => print(e.data().toString()));//this won't execute
    snap.docs.map((e) => print(e.data().toString()));//this won't execute
```

Why does `.map()` not work when the `for` loop does?

Comment: If you're not going to use the *result* of `List.map`, then `List.forEach` or a `for` loop would be more appropriate.  The point of using `List.map` is to create a new `List`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the way [`map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method works. According to the documentation -

> map<T> method
>
> ```
> Iterable<T> map <T>(
>
>     T f(
>         E e
>     )
>
> )
> ```
>
> Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling
> f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.
>
> This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the
> returned Iterable is not iterated over, the supplied function f will
> not be invoked. The transformed elements will not be cached. Iterating
> multiple times over the returned Iterable will invoke the supplied
> function f multiple times on the same element.
>
> Methods on the returned iterable are allowed to omit calling f on any
> element where the result isn't needed. For example, elementAt may call
> f only once.

In your example, because you are not iterating over the resulting `Iterable`, it won't invoke the function. So if you change your code to this

```
snap.docs.map((e) => print(e.data().toString())).toList();
```

then it will execute because now it needs to iterate over the resulting `Iterable` in order to convert it to a `List`.

Answer (score 3):

List.map creates an iterable but doesnt actually iterate over it. You can see it in this example:

```
List<String> s = ["a", "b", "c"];

var i = s.map((e){
  print(e);
});

i.toList(); //prints a, b, c
```

You can force it by calling .toList() like so:

```
List<String> s = ["a", "b", "c"];

var i = s.map((e){
  print(e);
}).toList(); //prints a,b,c

print(i.length); //3
```

Comment: Thank you your examples helped me understand the problem better