# About map function on dart

Tags: function, dictionary, dart

Here is my code, created one class and List of this this class. I tried to run map function but not working.

```
class Student {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int point;
  Student({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.point});
  Student.withId({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.point});
}

void main() {
  List<Student> students = [
  Student.withId(id: 1, firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Red', point: 90),
  Student.withId(id: 2, firstName: 'Dougles', lastName: 'Brown', point: 90),
  Student.withId(id: 3, firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'White', point: 90),
  ];
  students.map((student) {
    print(student.firstName);
  });

}
```

there is no output on this code. what is my fault.

Comment: And [List.map not executing despite List having elements inside(flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64584646/)

Comment: Maybe try to use `forEach` instead or `map().toList()`